# Code (in R) returning variable location not value

Tags: r

I have a database of past NFL games including "hometeam" and "awayteam" columns.  I am trying to create ) datafram referencing the games of a specific team (say Miami).  I am trying to set up an Opponents column in the new dataframe.  To do this, I need to pull data from either the hometeam or awayteam column from the original dataframe depending on if Miami is the away/home team respectively.  I am using an ifelse statement and I am getting the position of the opponent in alphabetical order instead of the team name.  For instance, I am getting 1 instead of Atlanta or 32 instead of Washington.

I am setting up a new variable in the new dataframe using ifelse statement.

NewSumm$team2 <- ifelse(olddata2$home == "Miami", olddata2$away, olddata2$home)

Comment: I think you have `factor` column.  So, you may need to convert to `character` class `ifelse(as.character(olddata2$home) == "Miami", as.character(olddata2$away), as.character(olddata2$home))`

Comment: Thank you.  That did it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `factor` column.  Within `ifelse`, it coerces to the `integer` storage mode.  To prevent that, we can convert to `character` and it should work

```
ifelse(as.character(olddata2$home) == "Miami", 
        as.character(olddata2$away), as.character(olddata2$home))
```